# Why am I getting an "Illegal string offset" error?

Tags: php

Why am I getting these errors?

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'en' in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\stream.class.php on line 48
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'en' in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\stream.class.php on line 60

Here's my code.

```
$s['target_data']['title'] = $s['target_data']['title']['en'];
$s['target_data']['description'] = $s['target_data']['description']['en'];
```

Comment: this error occured when i accidentally tried to use a $string variable considering it as an array and tried to add new values to array as `$string[] = $value['index']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$s['target_data']['title']` is a string, not an array as you seem to be expecting.

PHP allows you to use array-type syntax to index into a string (`$string[0]` returns the first character of `$string`, for example), but that only works with numeric indexes like `[0]` - you cannot use string indexes like `["en"]`, which is what the error is complaining about.

The code you showed seems to be trying to convert a variable from an array to a string and storing it back in the same variable. Could you perhaps be running it twice - and then getting the error the second time because it's no longer an array?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
   (array) $s['target_data']['title'] = (array) $s['target_data']['title']['en'];


   (array) $s['target_data']['description'] = (array)$s['target_data']['description']['en'];
```

if your  $s['target_data']['description'] and $s['target_data']['title'] are not arrays, you can cast it as (array)

Comment: That might fix the error, but it'll always return `null` (and possibly generate a warning for the undefined array index) - not very useful in actually finding the `en` element.

Comment: You're right, notice will be shown. If [en] index is null, so result always will be null. Then must be worked on [en] index